# Bootstrap 4 Navbar position

Tags: html, css, position, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am trying to make a navbar that hovers on top of 2 other items and then when it goes to mobile size I would like it to collapse but put the mobile icon at the top right of the screen like so:

[image: want]

I have no idea how to get it to hover on top of the two other items, I have tried to fiddle with z-index and offsets but I can't get it to sit right in the center of the two without white spaces on the side.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2gu0ffah/)

```css
#mu-carousel .carousel-item {
  max-height: 480px;
}

#mu-header {
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 135px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <header id="mu-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <span>LOGO/NAME</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <span>TEXT</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <span>TEXT</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <span>TEXT</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
          <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Dropdown link
                                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <section id="mu-carousel">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!--  JavaScript -->
  <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
  <script src="js/creative.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Which exactly are the "2 other items" the navbar is supposed to hover on top of?

Comment: First one is the header section with the logo and the text, the other is the carousel item. In the image I posted the topbar should be the header.

Comment: Aha, so the navbar is supposed to hover in between those items, not on top.

Comment: Maybe that would the better technical way of saying it but visually it would hover on top, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: *"I can't get it to sit right in the center"* -- does that mean the navbar items have to be centered?

Comment: I do want them centered eventually but that was not what I meant, when I was fiddling around the whole bar, so to say, would not be evenly distributed over (between) the two elements, the top would stick out more than the bottom or vice versa or ended up at some random position.

Comment: So, what I gather from this is that you want 50% of the navbar height to be over the header and the bottom 50% of the navbar height to be over the carousel, correct?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want, that is why I also posted the image along with it because I am terrible at describing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you just add `style="margin-top: -28px;"` to the navbar container (28px is half of the navbar height) and then add `style="margin-top: -28px;"` to the carousel container as well.

Finally, add the `sticky-top` to the navbar container.

To make it work for small screens the way it's shown in your picture, the navbar toggler has to be taken out of the navbar. I put it into a column located after the logo column in the HTML. (I've also given the toggle a background color to make it visible.)

The classes `d-flex justify-content-end` make the toggler right aligned and the class `d-md-none` makes sure that the toggler disappears on larger screens.

And since the navbar on small screens is only 16px tall (because the toggler was taken out) we need a custom class to control the negative top margin for small screens and for larger screens like so:

```
.mpush {
    margin-top: -8px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .mpush {
        margin-top: -28px;
    }
}
```

Here's the complete working snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
<style>
.mpush {
    margin-top: -8px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .mpush {
        margin-top: -28px;
    }
}
</style>

<header id="mu-header" style="height: 135px; background: lightgrey;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 col-md-6">
                <span>LOGO/NAME</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-4 d-flex d-md-none justify-content-end">
                <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right2 bg-warning" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span>TEXT</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span>TEXT</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <span>TEXT</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="container bg-warning sticky-top mpush">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Dropdown link
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="mu-carousel" class="mpush">
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/93140/pexels-photo-93140.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>

<p style="padding-top: 999px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate deleniti facilis corrupti dolores vero eaque, placeat saepe velit a officiis inventore itaque ipsa, temporibus. Est sint voluptatem natus veritatis in.</p>
```

Comment: That works like a charm on the desktop version for the mobile version however I had the idea as shown in the picture and with bootstrap you can pull and push columns, do they need to be inside the same row/container for that to work?

Comment: Thanks that works awesome. Edited it a little bit more: https://jsfiddle.net/vw67hk2v/2/ but coult not have done it without you, thanks again!